# jquery mobile error undefined call

Tags: jquery-mobile

Two problems that i am facing using jquery mobile link then when i am scrolling or do any actions on page its getting me this error many times.

jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined main.js:4
jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined main.js:4
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined

Second problem when i am using locally jquery mobile js and css file and add in my project
so images are not showing on buttons like back arrow on back button all images not availabe on any component like list views on all kind of stuff.

Comment: Without code we cannot help you

Comment: there is an internal jquery error RuJordan i just simply add files and when i am scrolling or perform some actions on browser there showing Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined in console of chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer for your second problem add the below images ajax-loader,icons-18-black,icons-36-black into following directory

```
   Your Project Folder
                   ---CSS Folder
                       ---create images folder
                          ----Add the above images
```